# URL rewrite matching incorrectly IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

So my URL is
'http://localhost:1272/pdp/Gitanjali-1GMRose995-24KtGoldCoin?id=GR-995-1GM-12269'. I want IIS to redirect to a certain page if the URL contains the word 'pdp'. But since this can also occur as part of the product name which I'm putting in the URL I want IIS to match `/pdp/` rather than just the word `pdp`.

This is what I tried:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="/pdp/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Product/ProductDisplay.aspx" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>


    <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="\/pdp\/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Product/ProductDisplay.aspx" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

Both of these rules are unable to match with the following:
http://localhost:1272/pdp/Gitanjali-1GMRose995-24KtGoldCoin?id=GR-995-1GM-12269

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please try :     <match url="\*/pdp/\*" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. since pdp is in the begining of the url the first / in /pdp/ is not required. removing that and making the condition as

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="pdp\/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Product/ProductDisplay.aspx" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

fixed the problem.